# error occurred while installing escape_utils (1.2.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

When running the rails server i am getting  "An error occurred while installing escape_utils (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install escape_utils -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling". But after that when i run bundle install, i have received the following error " error occurred while installing escape_utils (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install escape_utils -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling".

Could anyone guide me how to fix this?

Comment: Try adding it inside Gemfile like `gem 'escape_utils', '~> 1.2.1'` and do `bundle install`

Comment: @Pavan, yes i also tried it. But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `gem install escape_utils -v '1.2.1'` to install the gem without using bundler. It will probably fail and the trace that it prints will tell you what's happening and where to find the error log file for more info on what's missing.

That gem has native extensions that it needs to compile, if it gives you an error while compiling them, you probably have a missing system dependency.

Comment: Is there any other way to fix this?